# Javascript: Remove trailing chars from string if they are non-numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I am passing codes to an API. These codes are alphanumeric, like this one: M84.534D

I just found out that the API does not use the trailing letters. In other words, the API is expecting M84.534, no letter D at the end.
The problem I am having is that the format is not the same for the codes.
I may have M84.534DAC, or M84.534.

What I need to accomplish before sending the code is to remove any non-numeric characters from the end of the code, so in the examples:

M84.534D -> I need to pass M84.534

M84.534DAC -> I also need to pass M84.534

Is there any function or regex that will do that?

Thank you in advance to all.

Comment: There is a regex. `$` denotes 'ends with', and combine with the digit operator maybe? `/\d+$/` might be the right path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex below. It will remove anything from the end of the string that is not a number

```js
let code = 'M84.534DAC'

console.log(code.replace(/[^0-9]+?$/, ""));
```

- `[^0-9]` matches anything that is not a numer
- `+?` Will match between 1 and unlimited times
- `$` Will match the end of the string

So linked together, it will match any non numbers at the end of the string, and replace them with nothing.

Comment: Updated with a description

Comment: Works perfectly! As soon as it allows me, I mark it as Solved! I appreciate all the answers! Thank you @user184994 for the clear explanation.

Comment: There's no need for the `?` modifier since it's anchored at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following expression:

```
\D*$
```

As in:

```js
var somestring = "M84.534D".replace(/\D*$/, '');
console.log(somestring);
```

**Explanation:**
`\D` stands for *not* `\d`, the star `*` means zero or more times (greedily) and the `$` anchors the expression to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to answer and explain. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your limited data sample, this simple regular expression does the trick. You just replace the match with an empty string.

I've used `document.write` just so we can see the results. You use this whatever way you want.

```js
var testData = [
  'M84.534D',
  'M84.534DAC'
]

regex = /\D+$/

testData.forEach((item) => {
   var cleanValue = item.replace(regex, '')
   document.write(cleanValue + '<br>')
})
```

RegEx breakdown:
`\D` = Anything that's not a digit
`+` = One or more occurrences
`$` = End of line/input